# Special chars in filename causing issues

Tags: php

```
$imageURL = 'http://www.cnsnews.com/sites/default/files/images/OBAMA-AP%20PHOTO_8.jpg';

$imageInfo = pathinfo($imageURL);
$imageName = clean(basename($imageURL,'.'.$imageInfo['extension']));
$fileName =  $imageName.'.'.$imageInfo['extension'];// file name

$content = file_get_contents($imageURL);

file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName, $content);   
$product_file = UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName;


function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
}
```

.. although almost all urls I've tried work fine except this one, probably because of the special chars in `OBAMA-AP%20PHOTO_8.jpg`? even though I'm cleaning it?

The image doesn't get downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(editing my previous answer, it wasn't very helpful)

triage the problem -- does the `file_get_contents($imageURL)` return data?
Print the length of the returned string to test, `echo strlen($contents);`

Can you create a file that contains a '%' in the filename?

I can download the imageURL as typed, so you're most likely right, it's
the % in the save-to filename that's going to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before cleaning the image name, you should urldecode it:

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = urldecode($string);
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
}
```

Comment: I tried the file_get_contents and it works well. Because you are downloading an image that is on a remote server, you need allow_url_fopen to be enabled. Can you check your php.ini and make sure it's enabled? Also, can you paste how you define UPLOAD_DIR?

Comment: but why would it choke on just this file only and not others?

Comment: Are other files remote too?

Comment: As Andras suggested, can you `echo strlen($contents);` to see if the file is actually downloaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70526/discussion-between-adrien-and-3zzy).